# jQuery - Code running even when condition isn't met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

The things here are like this (long story but I have a point)

I have a menu with buttons that look like this:

```
*******
***B***
*******
```

An when you hover it expands

```
*************
***Button****
*************
```

Now, when the screen is for mobile, no more hexagons, they stack up like normal buttons, with the complete text showing instead of having to hover to read.

my markup is as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">S<span class="comptxt">ervicios</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn">C<span class="comptxt">ontacto</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn">F<span class="comptxt">aq</span></a>
<a href="#" class="btn">B<span class="comptxt">log</span></a>
```

And I'm using jQuery to show and hide the span tags on hover and css to handle the width of the anchor tag.

```
$('a.btn').hover(function() {
                $(this).children('span').fadeIn(500);
                $('img').css('opacity', 0.5);
            }, function() {
                $(this).children('span').fadeOut(200);
                $('img').css('opacity', 1);
            });
```

so fade in on hover fade out when not hover.
BUT I put this javascript on an IF conditional, if the screen resizes to mobile (i'm using 500px and below as mobile) this code shouldn't run, here is the if conditional:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < '501') {
        $('a.btn').hover(function() {
                $(this).children('span');
                $('img').css('opacity', 0.5);
            }, function() {
                $(this).children('span');
                $('img').css('opacity', 1);
            });
    };
    if ($(window).width() > '500') {
            $('a.btn').hover(function() {
                console.log($(window).width());
                $(this).children('span').fadeIn(500);
                $('img').css('opacity', 0.5);
            }, function() {
                //this part of the code runs even if the window is below 500
                $(this).children('span').fadeOut(200);
                $('img').css('opacity', 1);
            });

    };
});
```

It's freaking me out that the conditional doesn't met and the code still runs.
Tha problem with this is that when the buttons are normal and you hover over them after the resize, the text fades out
Other thing: when you load the page and the screen is below 500 it works as it should, no fading out. The problem arises when you resize above 500 and resize back down below 500, then the fadeout happens again.

Comment: Because you never unbind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the resize event you never remove the previous event handler from when the window was at a larger size. You can achieve this using `off()`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < '501') {
        $('a.btn').off('hover').hover(function() {
            // rest of your code...
        });
    };
    if ($(window).width() > '500') {
        $('a.btn').off('hover').hover(function() {
            // rest of your code...
        });
    };
});
```

A better solution may be to instead check the size of the window within the `hover` handler itself as detaching/attaching events for every single pixel that the window is resized is going to end up being very slow. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.btn').hover(function() {
        var opacity = $(window).width() < 501 ? 0.5 : 1;
        $('img').css('opacity', opacity);
    }, function() {
        var opacity = $(window).width() < 501 ? 1 : 0.5;
        $('img').css('opacity', opacity);
    });
});
```

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Thak you! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()`, like `.click()` and other functions, are additive with jQuery.

Every time the window is resised, you bind an additional function on hover.

I mean, if the window is resized by 200 pixels, you bind the function 200 times, and it will actually be executed 200 times on hover.

It's also true when you expand the window : hover functions will continue to be bond. So, on hover, 200 "small screen" functions will be executed, and 200 "large screen" functions will be executed. This is a terrible design.

At least, you have to unbind hover() before applying a new one :

```
$('a.btn').unbind('mouseover mouseout').hover(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not run, because you put it inside $(window).resize. It will only run when the screen is resized, but never on hover.